# Como solucionar paso 52 del curso CSS

Tags: css

No sé cómo puedo solucionar este problema, he intentado varias cosas, pero no puedo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado `.flavor.dessert`, `.flavor .dessert` `.dessert.flavor`

Comment: El selector es lo que está antes de las llaves. Te pide que agregues `.dessert` al lado de `.flavor`: `.flavor.dessert`. Cuidado que `.flavor .dessert` es diferente. Con esta variante quieres decir que el estilo se aplica a un elemento con la clase `dessert`, hijo de un elemento con la clase `flavor`.

Comment: Ya lo había intentado anteriormente, lo volvi a probar pero el `.flavor.dessert` no me da un resultado positivo, me dice el mismo error y no da mas pistas.

Comment: Has intentado asi: `.flavor > .dessert{ /*aqui tus estilos*/}` o  `.dessert > .flavor{ /*aqui tus estilos*/}` Con eso estas diciendo que seleccione los elementos con clase flavor/dessert que se encuentran dentro de la clase dessert/flavor

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que a los elementos que tienen la clase flavor y a los que tienen desert se les apliquen las mismas propiedades pon .flavor, .desert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que no eres el único.
Googleando el curso (porque tambien tomé hace tiempo un curso con los mismos ejemplos de esas clases) Alguien mas presentaba el mismo problema. y en efecto parece ser que es la falta de coma para separar una clase de otra.

[Duda original](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/responsive-web-design-beta-learn-css-by-building-a-cafe-menu/494738)

Esta es una sintaxis incorrecta:`.flavor.dessert` `.flavor .dessert` `.dessert.flavor` ya que no hay separadores, en todo caso si vamos a utilizar una sintaxis similar sería para seleccionar a una etiqueta seguida de su clase, por ejemplo: `div.example` `div.flavor` `p.donut`

Para seleccionar puede utilizar incluso operadores como > + ,
ejemplo:

`div.flavor > p.donut {}`
(Selecciona a los elementos p de clase donut que se encuentren dentro del div con clase flavor)

`div.flavor + div.dessert {}`
(Selecciona a los elementos div con clase flavor y a los elementos div con clase dessert)

`.dessert, .flavor{}`
(Selecciona a las clases desert y flavor)

Answer (score 1):

La solucion fue colocar una coma en medio de las dos clases, Muchas Gracias

```
CSS 
.flavor, .dessert{
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
}
```

[image]